# Countif dates in two table columns are different

Tags: excel, countif, sumproduct

I have a bit of an issue. Why else would I be here? ;)

I have a table (table1) and in this table I have two columns that I would like to count if the dates differ (Task due date and Task complete date). What I want to do is calculate the task that are past due or delivered on time. (Yes I am aware that free templates are available, this is mainly to learn more on working with Excel)

In my calculation sheet, I want to count:

1. The amount of Task complete dates that are prior or equal (<=) then the Task due date
2. The amount of Task complete dates that are past (>) the Task due date

I think that the issue lays in in the `COUNTIF` statement because it seems to only accept one array (the count array) after that comes the criteria which does not seem to handle arrays.

I also tried `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Table1[Task complete date];"<=" & Table1[Task due date]))` But this gives me a value of 8 (while I have two possible matches)

According to [This tutorial](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-total-matches-in-two-ranges), I should get a return value of 1 and 0 but looking at the calculation steps I get: `SUMPRODUCT({1;1;2;2;2;0;0;0;0;0})` This would off course be where the value of 8 comes from.

Is there any way around this? Do I need to add in some kind of `if` statement or some kind of pre-check?

[Here is a link to the excel document with some test data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XZTFZ4TPKOHYrccjKevfKcxXtUw1yo2O/view?usp=sharing)

Oh and by the way: the comma delimitter in my country is a `;` and not an actual comma. That is why there are semicolumns where some of you would expect a comma.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Tinus

Comment: Do you also have a sample table to work with?

Comment: A sample table? type it.

Comment: I added in a link to the original document. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a date check to column M in your "Project tasks" table: `=IF(COUNTBLANK(F4)+COUNTBLANK(K4)=0,IF([@[Task due date]]<=[@[Task complete date]],"On time","Past Due"),"")`.

Then you could use `=COUNTIF(Table1[Date check],[@[on time/past due]])` in column K of your "Data" sheet.

P.S. If you need a translation of the given function you may check https://de.excel-translator.de/

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does seem to do the trick. However, since I have to create more checks I would want to prevent these check columns because it would need a multitude of check columns.

Comment: Are you allowed to use PowerQuery? It would allow you to easily code all those checks without using any formula.

Comment: It is my own document so I guess yes, I could use powerquery. I am mainly trying this to gain more knowledge on Excel and if I can find a good use for this project tracking tool then that would be great.

Comment: I have uploaded an Excel file, in which I used PowerQuery to do that check: <  https://tmpfiles.org/dl/58823/projectstatustrackerpq.xlsx> (it will only be available for one hour). Go to ribbon "data" and click on something like "query and connections". This will show a side bar with two entries (if it has not been there already). Click on "check_date" and the PowerQuery editor will open.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting values above 1 is that your COUNTIF is actually comparing **each value in Table1[Task complete date]** to **each value in Table1[Task due date]**.  e.g. if the [Task complete date] is 1 Jan, it will count how many [Task due date] values are greater than or equal to 1 Jan, so that could be 2, for example. Then it moves to the next value in [Task complete date] and does the same.

So you would need to do:

**The amount of Task complete dates that are prior or equal (<=) then the Task due date**

```
=SUM(--(Table1[Task complete date]<=Table1[Task due date]))
```

**The amount of Task complete dates that are past (>) the Task due date**

```
=SUM(--(Table1[Task complete date]>Table1[Task due date]))
```

**Additional Notes**

For versions of Excel before 2019 or Excel 365, the formulas above must be entered as array formulas, so you have to enter them with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. For your Google Sheets version, these must also be array formulas, but you will also need some additional filtering to get it to ignore blank cells.  You could do:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM((K4:K24<=F4:F24)*(K4:K24>0)))
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM((K4:K24>F4:F24)*(K4:K24>0)))
```

Comment: Interesting solution, i did not know about the two minus signs operator. How would you handle the case in which a "task complete data" does not exist?

Comment: This gives me a value of <= 1 and > 0 while I should be getting <= 2 and > 1 based on the test values

Comment: @Qualia -- is called "coercing". You can coerce boolean TRUE/FALSE into 1/0 by multiplying the boolean times another boolean or number value. Since there is nothing to multiply these values against, you can multiply them times themselves by taking the negative of them and then converting that back to positive by taking it again, thus: --.

Comment: @tinus087 I was responding directly to the question as to why `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Table1[Task complete date];"<=" & Table1[Task due date]))` is generating {1;1;2;2;2;0;0;0;0;0} and what you could replace that formula with. If you are using GSheets or a pre-Excel 2019 version of Excel, then you need to enter my proposed formula as an array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).  I will add a comment about Google Sheets to the answer, because it will require more than the proposed Excel approach.

Comment: @Qualia - I was just looking at the specific question about why SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF approach was generating values other than 0 and 1.  I just added a filter to ignore the rows where there is no Complete Date and put that into the answer. By multiplying the condition (K4:K24>0) times the original boolean condition, it now achieves coercion without having to use --, so that is now removed from the formula.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick: Thanks a lot for your explanations. I really appreciate them.